# Display stock status on product detail

Tags: magento2, stock-status

I'm trying to figure out how to show stock status on product page (In stock/Out of stock). I tried to [change stock message from the Catalog page](https://meetanshi.com/blog/display-stock-availability-message-on-product-page-in-magento-2/) but it didn't work ! I guess its because I use a custom theme.

Any tips ?
Thanks.

Comment: first of all change to default theme from backend "Magento Blank or Luma" and check on detail page. message is there or not?

Comment: Yes the message appears !

Comment: that mean your custom theme  overrided that code and removed this message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to

> /app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and search for

`<referenceBlock name='product.info.stock.sku' remove='true'/>`

change it to

```
<referenceBlock name='product.info.stock.sku' remove='false'/>
```

hope it helps you

Comment: It worked ! "In stock" is now displayed alongside with sku (which I prefer be hidden). But when a product is out of stock, "In stock" is still displayed, but i guess that a problem for another question. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: happy to hear it helps you

Comment: Oops, I forgot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Admin panel -> Go to -> store -> configuration-> Catalog -> Inventory -> Display Products Availability in Stock on Storefront ->Select Yes from the dropdown -> Click on save config button !

Clear the cache and check at frontend - it will not display !